# Make laravel ignore route parameters for AngularJS to pick them up

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I am working on an AngularJS (version 1.6) app. The back-end of this app is made in Laravel (version 5.3).

The routing of the app is done by AngularJS. To be able to us Angular's `html5Mode`, I made a catch route that returns my index view like this:

```
Route::get('{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

From here on, Angular handles all the routing. However, I now face the problem that I can't use route parameters. If I for example went to the url: `http://example.com/profile/username` Laravels routing would take the upper hand again and show me a `NotFoundHttpException`

Is there a possibility for me to either do something like this:

```
Route::get('{all}/{all}', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Or maybe the possibility to disable Laravel's routing in full, with an exeption of the `/api/` routes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function (){
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

this should route to angular with the url param